# opening accordian from another page

Tags: jquery

I am trying to open an accordian state from a link on another page using id's, so LINK1 would open accordian 1 , LINK 2 would open accordian 2 etc - been trying to find the correct logic to achieve this.

Can anyone give me some pointers

Answer (score 0):

you could save the link clicks on cookie variable.. and you need to continuously check for the current cookie variable storing the link clicked (in page containing accordion ). then trigger change accordion according to this

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open new page with accordion expanded you should use something like this:

Link to page

```
<a href="page.html#accordian1">Link 1</a>
```

And jQuery in linked page:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var hash = window.location.hash;
  $(hash).collapse('show');
});
```

If you want to expand accordion in already opened page from another page then you have to use cookies as @sarath answered